# Display message in today widget when no data is available

Tags: swift

I have just add a today widget to my app and it seems to be working well. The one thing I have noticed is that before the app is opened for the first time the widget displays a message 'Unable to load'.

I was wondering how I could display a message when there is no data to show (since the app has never been used) that says something like "Nothing to display. Tap here to launch APPNAME to get started"?

Here is my current code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320,60)
}

@IBAction func launchApp(sender: AnyObject) {
    var url: NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString("APPNAME://")
    self.extensionContext.openURL(url, completionHandler: nil)
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320,60)

    var currentBudgetCalculation = ""
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.APPNAME")
    currentBudgetCalculation = defaults.stringForKey("currentBudgetWidget")!
    currentBudgetDisplay.text = "Current: \(currentBudgetCalculation)"

    var totalBudgetCalculation = ""
    totalBudgetCalculation = defaults.stringForKey("totalBudgetWidget")!
    totalBudgetDisplay.text = "Initial: \(totalBudgetCalculation)"

    var budgetName = defaults.stringForKey("name")
    budgetNameDisplay.text = budgetName

    var valueFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    valueFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    var doubleValue = valueFormatter.numberFromString(currentBudgetCalculation)?.doubleValue

    if doubleValue > 0 {
        currentBudgetDisplay.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    } else if doubleValue == 0 {
        currentBudgetDisplay.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    } else if doubleValue < 0 {
        currentBudgetDisplay.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}

func widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets(defaultMarginInsets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    let newInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: defaultMarginInsets.top, left: 0,
        bottom: 0, right: defaultMarginInsets.right)
    return newInsets
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((NCUpdateResult) -> Void)!) {
    // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

    // If an error is encoutered, use NCUpdateResult.Failed
    // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResult.NoData
    // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResult.NewData

    completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.NewData)
}
```

}